# How to refresh just specific code with javascript setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, gps, gis

I have a code like this :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>GPS Tracker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view/style.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function show_maps()
  {

    var div_peta = document.getElementById('kanvas');
    var tengah = new google.maps.LatLng(-8.801502,115.174794);
    var options = 
    {
      center : tengah,
      zoom : 14,
      mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    //make map object
    var google_map = new google.maps.Map(div_peta,options);

  }
</script>
</head>
<body OnLoad="show_maps();">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"><div class="panel panel-default panel-body">
<p><b><h4>Tracking</h4></b><hr>
<form method="GET" action="../controller/location.php">
          <p><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="get location" style="width:280px"></a></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="panel panel-default panel-body" style="height:490px">
           <div id="kanvas"> kanvas peta</div>
      </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make a GPS tracking system. the method to get the location is by SMS. once the "get location" button clicked, the SMS to ask for location is delivered. so, I need to refresh the map every second until the GPS tracker reply the SMS. so I can take the data to create a marker on google map. I don't want to refresh the whole page. I just want to refresh the google map. is there a way to do that with setTimeout?
thank you...

Comment: You can do that with `setInterval`. See my answer an demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060496/how-to-refresh-just-specific-code-with-javascript-settimeout/24060912#24060912)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
var i = setInterval(show_maps, 1000);
```

if you want to stop the interval

```
clearInterval(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/3a5RB/)**

You can use following structure. Your map will be reload in every 5 seconds;

```
var mapsLoaded = false;
window.mapsCallback = function(){
    mapsLoaded = true;
    setInterval(function(){
        $(window).trigger('mapsLoaded');
    }, 5000);
}
window.loadMaps = function(){
    if(mapsLoaded) return window.mapsCallback();
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src","http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=mapsCallback");
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    function initialize(){
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.3239, 5.0428),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('kanvas'),mapOptions);
    }
    $(window).bind('mapsLoaded', initialize);
    window.loadMaps();
});
```